# SyntaxError within simple setInterval function

Tags: javascript, setinterval

I want to start changing the background color of a div on mouseover in loop of 2 seconds
So the html code:

```
<div onmousemove="start_loop(this)"></div>
```

and the javascript function:

```
function start_loop(theDiv) {
    ms = setInterval("changeBg("+theDiv+")", 2000);
}
```

but I got this error:

```
SyntaxError: missing ] after element list

start_loop([object HTMLDivElement])
```

Comment: And this is why you pass function references or anonymous functions to `setInterval()` rather than strings that contain JavaScript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`theDiv` is not a string, it's a DOM element, so using string concatenation won't do anything useful. Try:

```
var ms;

function start_loop(theDiv) {
    if (!ms) {
        ms = setInterval(function() {
            changeBg(theDiv);
            }, 2000);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Barmar, it's work now but I got another problem, I have multiple intervals doing the same job each time the mouse move over the div so how can I check if the interval is not exist before creating it?

Comment: It seems like the solution is pretty obvious, but I updated the answer to show it.

Comment: I tried that before asking but I got ReferenceError: ms is not defined

Comment: Try initializing it with `var ms = null`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an anonymous function inside your setInterval.Thats it

```
functionstart_loop(param){
//some code
}

 ms=setInterval( function() { loop(param) }, 2000);
```